# Framed longtable using fbox

Tags: longtable

To make a framed `longtable` I tried the following code using `\fbox` and `\minipage`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}\textbf{}
\centering\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \begin{longtable}{lcc}
        Number & Odd/Even \\
        \hline
        1   &   Odd \\
        2   &   Even    \\
        3   &   Odd \\
        4   &   Even    \\
        5   &   Odd \\
        6   &   Even    \\
        7   &   Odd \\
        8   &   Even    \\
        9   &   Odd \\
        10  &   Even    \\
        11  &   Odd \\
        12  &   Even    \\
        13  &   Odd \\
        14  &   Even    \\
        15  &   Odd \\
        16  &   Even    \\
        17  &   Odd \\
        18  &   Even    \\
        19  &   Odd \\
        20  &   Even    \\
        21  &   Odd \\
        22  &   Even    \\
        23  &   Odd \\
        24  &   Even    \\
        25  &   Odd \\
        26  &   Even    \\
        27  &   Odd \\
        28  &   Even    \\
        29  &   Odd \\
        30  &   Even    \\
        31  &   Odd \\
        32  &   Even    \\
        33  &   Odd \\
        34  &   Even    \\
        35  &   Odd \\
        36  &   Even    \\
        37  &   Odd \\
        38  &   Even    \\
        39  &   Odd \\
        40  &   Even    \\
        41  &   Odd \\
        42  &   Even    \\
        43  &   Odd \\
        44  &   Even    \\
        45  &   Odd \\
        46  &   Even    \\
        47  &   Odd \\
        48  &   Even    \\
        49  &   Odd \\
        50  &   Even    \\
\end{longtable}
\end{minipage} }
\end{document}
```

However, the table is build on page 2 and the `longtable` (long table on multiple pages) does not work unfortunately.

Comment: `minipage` and `longtable` isn't a very good idea nor is the non-breakable `\fbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `longtable` in a non-breakable `minipage` and this in the non-breakable `\fbox` is weird.

If the table should be boxed and breakable, it's possible to use `tcolorbox` and it's breakable feature.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{tabframebox}[1][]{breakable,sharp corners,boxrule=0.5pt,colback=white,halign=center,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabframebox}
    \begin{longtable}{lcc}
        Number & Odd/Even \\
        \hline
        1   &   Odd \\
        2   &   Even    \\
        3   &   Odd \\
        4   &   Even    \\
        5   &   Odd \\
        6   &   Even    \\
        7   &   Odd \\
        8   &   Even    \\
        9   &   Odd \\
        10  &   Even    \\
        11  &   Odd \\
        12  &   Even    \\
        13  &   Odd \\
        14  &   Even    \\
        15  &   Odd \\
        16  &   Even    \\
        17  &   Odd \\
        18  &   Even    \\
        19  &   Odd \\
        20  &   Even    \\
        21  &   Odd \\
        22  &   Even    \\
        23  &   Odd \\
        24  &   Even    \\
        25  &   Odd \\
        26  &   Even    \\
        27  &   Odd \\
        28  &   Even    \\
        29  &   Odd \\
        30  &   Even    \\
        31  &   Odd \\
        32  &   Even    \\
        33  &   Odd \\
        34  &   Even    \\
        35  &   Odd \\
        36  &   Even    \\
        37  &   Odd \\
        38  &   Even    \\
        39  &   Odd \\
        40  &   Even    \\
        41  &   Odd \\
        42  &   Even    \\
        43  &   Odd \\
        44  &   Even    \\
        45  &   Odd \\
        46  &   Even    \\
        47  &   Odd \\
        48  &   Even    \\
        49  &   Odd \\
        50  &   Even    \\
\end{longtable}
\end{tabframebox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks this works, although not perfectly: the boxes on both pages are not closed

Comment: @API: Remove the `enhanced jigsaw` option!

Comment: the table header repetition every page, using `\endhead` after defining the header, does not work anymore.

Comment: @API: Yes, that's undesirable, but that wasn't in your question. The easiest thing is to use draw the frame with the `hline` and `|` etc. directly, without using an outer box